# How to trigger event on copy,cut or paste option clicked from mouse options in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I trigger the event, when the user selects only copy,cut or paste option from mouse context menus.

Comment: Send me the code snippet that you have tried

Comment: If you are trying to do a cut,copy,paste functionality, usually it is not possible using pure JS, you would need some external library like zeroclipboard inorder to do that....

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know when a user has changed an input due to context menu actions, and you have decent browser support, you can use the `input` event.  It fires when a user interacts with the input in any way (including the mouse/context menu)

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x8ph46b6/1/

Comment: Thanks justinaray. it helps.